# edit_subject.php is not working, the error is saying about database query failed

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

This is kind of the error I'm getting:

> Database query failed.

I've uploaded this webpage: http://widgetcorp.bugs3.com/public/edit_subject.php?subject=1

Here's my file:

```
<?php require_once("../includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/validation_functions.php"); ?>
<?php find_selected_page(); ?>
<?php 
    if (!$current_subject)
        {
            // subject ID was missing or invalid or
            // subject couldn't be found in database
            redirect_to("manage_content.php");
        }
?>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        // validations
        $required_fields = array("menu_name", "position", "visible");           
        validate_presences($required_fields);

        $fields_with_max_lengths = array("menu_name" => 30);
        validate_max_lengths($fields_with_max_lengths);

        if (empty($errors))
            {
                // Perform Update

                $id = $current_subject["id"];
                $menu_name = mysql_prep($_POST["menu_name"]);
                $position = (int) $_POST["position"];
                $visible = (int) $_POST["visible"];

                $query  = "UPDATE subjects SET ";
                $query .= "menu_name='{$menu_name}', ";
                $query .= "position={$position}, ";
                $query .= "visible={$visible} ";
                $query .= "WHERE id={$id} ";
                $query .= "LIMIT 1";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection) >= 0)
                    {
                        // Success
                        $_SESSION["message"] = "Subject updated.";
                        redirect_to("manage_content.php");
                    } 
                else
                    {
                        // Failure
                        $message = "Subject update failed.";
                    }
            }
    }           
    // else
        // {
            // // This is probably a GET request
        // }  
?>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/header.php"); ?>
<div id="main">
    <div id="navigation">
        <?php  
             echo navigation($current_subject, $current_page);
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="page">
        <?php 
            // echo message(); 
            // $message is just a variable, doesn't use the SESSION
            if(!empty($message))
                {
                    echo "<div class=\"message\">" . htmlentities($message) . "</div>";
                }
        ?>
        <?php echo form_errors($errors); ?>
        <h2>Edit Subject: <?php echo htmlentities($current_subject["menu_name"]); ?></h2>

        <form action="edit_subject.php?subject=<?php echo htmlentities($current_subject["menu_name"]); ?>" method="post">

            <p>Menu name:
                <input type="text" name="menu_name" value="<?php echo htmlentities($current_subject["menu_name"]); ?>" />
            </p>

            <p>Position:
                <select name="position">
                <?php
                    $subject_set = find_all_subjects();
                    $subject_count = mysqli_num_rows($subject_set);
                    for ($count=1; $count <= $subject_count; $count++)
                        {
                            echo "<option value=\"{$count}\"";
                            if ($current_subject["position"] == $count)
                                {
                                    echo " selected";
                                }
                            echo ">{$count}</option>";
                        }
                ?>
                </select>
            </p>

            <p>Visible:
                <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0" <?php if ($current_subject["visible"] == 0) { echo "checked"; } ?> /> No
                &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1" <?php if ($current_subject["visible"] == 1) { echo "checked"; } ?> /> Yes
            </p>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Subject" />
        </form>
        <br />
        <a href="manage_content.php">Cancel</a>
        &nbsp;
        &nbsp;
        <a href="delete_subject.php?subject=<?php echo urlencode($current_subject["id"]); ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">Delete Subject</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: minimize your code and show where actually you getting the error. also share the error message

Comment: maybe missing quotes for values in update statement?

Comment: `mysql_prep` is not a PHP-provided function, and I guess its purpose is to escape the data in the user-supplied variable. You should really switch to parameterisation instead, though I don't think this is the actual problem.

Comment: What line is causing the failure, Rehan? Is it the `// Failure` section that produces the message? If so, work out why the `if` clause behaves that way. What value is `$result`? If it is `false` then maybe your `mysqli_query` failed?

Comment: I was following instruction from Mr. Kevin Skoglund's tutorial by the name of Learn PHP with MySQL with essential training, everything went all-right before or after editing subject tutorial, I can't believe how his code was working on his video tutorial but not mine, If you need respected files, I can send you directly because I was trying to learn PHP not to finalize any project, Mr. halfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is somewhere else and not with your `UPDATE` query actually. If you see the link you posted, you are passing `subject` parameter with url, whose value is `1` which is integer.

Now when you click submit it's changing the url to http://widgetcorp.bugs3.com/public/edit_subject.php?subject=About%20Widget%20Corp .

Here as you see the `subject` parameter is not `integer` but `string` value name of subject. And that is causing the problem.

You are getting error as it's not retrieving the subject data from database correctly because of wrong id type. You just need to make sure the form is being posted to right url, which would be  http://widgetcorp.bugs3.com/public/edit_subject.php?subject=1.

You need to correct the `action` parameter on the `<form>` tag for that.

Look for the line below in your code:

`<form action="edit_subject.php?subject=<?php echo htmlentities($current_subject["menu_name"]); ?>" method="post">`

And change it to

`<form action="edit_subject.php?subject=<?php echo htmlentities($current_subject["id"]); ?>" method="post">`

If you see, now the form will be submitted to http://widgetcorp.bugs3.com/public/edit_subject.php?subject=1, which is the correct url.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Vivek, please help me some more to fix whatever there's problem. Do you need the files to look more closely, I can send?

Comment: I thank you gladly, Mr. Vivek, It worked, in my local server and I'm going to upload this file very soon with ftp, there is one little issue, did you noticed my css file is not working the same for http://widgetcorp.bugs3.com/public/edit_subject.php as it was supposed to, as it is working correctly http://widgetcorp.bugs3.com/public/manage_content.php. Can you tell me why is that and what are the php codes which are affecting my css file, is it even possible?